# How do I execute a javascript function by modifying the URL of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, url

So, let's assume I have an HTML page (example.com/test.html) that has a few defined javascript functions, one of which is function play().  How would I inject javascript into the URL so that the play() function is called when the page loads?

Comment: simple answer use a routing system that attaches callbacks to specific HTML files. And load the routing js in each html file

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons, this is not possible.

Otherwise, I could give you a URL to your bank that runs Javascript to transfer money to my account.

However, you can modify the *page* to run Javascript whenever you want, or to read parameters from the URL and execute Javascript based on the parameters.
Don't make a page that runs arbitrary Javascript from the URL, or you'll have an XSS hole.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this through the URL, you do this within the Javascript on the page itself:

```
<script language="javascript">
// Assign an anonymous function to the onload event
window.onload = function(){
   // Place code to execute here.
}
</script>
```

Comment: i'm aware of how to do it within the page itself. i need to do it via the URL (i won't be able to change the html file)